# Datatables Paging is not working

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm new in using JQuery DataTables.
My problem is the following:

I have 157 entries in my Table. I set PageLength to 10 and paging to true.
When loading the page, Datatables show me the first 10 entries but when i go to page 2, Datatables show me all entries in the Table except the rows from page 1.

On my other page I use the same code and everything works perfectly.

Datatables is loaded like this:

```
var table = $('#myArchiveTable').DataTable({
            order: [[1, 'desc']],
            paging: true,
            pageLength: '10',

            ...
```

Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: Can you add full code instead of completing it by adding "...".

Comment: Oh sorry, but the problem is solved already. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `pageLength: '10'` from the datatable properties and try again.

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        paging: true,
        //pageLength: '10',
    });
});
```

To change the default length, try:

```
"lengthMenu": [[25, 50, -1], [25, 50, "All"]]
```

[Working Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/3311/)

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you help me on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63360592/search-and-pagination-not-working-while-using-server-side

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with:

```
pageLength: '10'
```

It should be:

```
pageLength: 10
```

in order to be treated as a number.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/3312/) based on [Mayank Pandeyz's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5921745/mayank-pandeyz) answer.

Comment: Thank you for providing the additional details. I converted pageLength value to integer using JavaScript function parseInt() and it worked.